# How do I remove postgres from Homebrew

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

In my `/usr/local/var/` I see there are directories of `postgresql@9.6`, `postgresql@9.5`, even after I ran `brew uninstall postgresql@9.6`. How do I get rid of these directories?

Answer (score 1):

It does contain your data, this is why it's not deleted. Say you had trouble with postgres, and decided to reinstall it, you don't want to lose your data because of it. If you did a migration of your databases to a new version or don't need any of the databases anymore you can just delete these folders manually.